# I look forward to hearing from you or looking forward to hear from you?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, verb-forms, to-infinitive

Should I say

> I look forward to **hearing** from you

or

> looking forward to **hear** from you?

I have doubt because I know that the form of a verb is "to+ infinity" without the addition of the -**ing** that changes it to become a noun.

Comment: "I look forward to hearing from you"
has more aesthetics about it.
The second however may not come across in the manner you wish it as quite a few people may even find it wrong to hear.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a very common mistake!
So, don't worry. Here is the cure.

Ask yourself which one makes more sense: "look forward **to it**" or "look forward **to do it**"?

Chances are you know that "look forward **to it**" sounds more natural, because you've seen or you've heard others use it that way before. And, yes, with ***look forward to***, you need ***hearing from you*** (NOT <del>*hear from you*</del>).

---

#### Grammar points

The trick is to remember that ***to*** can be either the **infinitive marker** or a **preposition**<sup>1</sup>.

You need a **verb** after the **infinitive marker** ***to*** (e.g. *I want to swim this evening*).
You need a **noun** after a **preposition** (e.g. *She went back to the pool*.)

> It doesn't have to be a real noun, just something that functions like a noun. In other words, it's [the object of a preposition](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/objprepterm.htm), as it's traditionally called; or as defined a little more precisely (same link):
>
> > The **prepositional complement** is typically a **noun phrase**, but it may also be a **nominal relative clause** or an ***-ing* clause**. Both the nominal relative clause and the *-ing* clause have a range of functions similar to that of a noun phrase: ...
> > <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

In your example, *to* in *[look forward to](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/look-forward-to)* is a preposition. Why? Because you can say ***look forward to something*** (e.g. *He had worked hard and was looking forward to his retirement.*) In other words, saying *"I'm looking forward to **it**"* makes sense.

And that makes you need a noun or something noun-like, i.e., ***hearing***, not *hear*:
*I look/'m looking forward to **hearing from you***.

<sup>1</sup><sub>When the preposition *to* is used in a phrasal verb, some people call it a [particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle), but let's keep this post simple and use only the term "infinitive marker" and "preposition".) Here is [a list of such phrasal verbs (ending with *to*)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_phrasal_verbs_with_particle_%28to%29). Some common ones, in my opinion, are *look forward to* and *be used to*. Another common phrasal verb (but not on that page) is *object to*.</sub>

---

#### Bonus

Here is a related mistake which shares the same cause of confusion: [***used to*** vs. ***be used to***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/used-to_1).

Remembering this may be helpful:

> *He **used to live** in Frankfurt, but **he's not used to living** in cold weather.*

The first *to* is the infinitive marker *to*. The second *to* is a preposition.
The first *to* is about "He used to do something".
The second *to* is about "He's not used to something".

Comment: Thank you. By the way, what is more formal / acceptable / common?

Comment: @Assiduous There is no choice between *look forward to hear* and *look forward to hearing*. Only one is grammatical: *look forward to hearing (from you)*.

Comment: @Assiduous Your comment reminds me of another possible issue: the choice between *look forward to* and *[be] looking forward to*. IMHO, it's better to treat the two issues separately. If you're interesting in the other issue (i.e. the progressive aspect), you may find my old answer useful: ["Also, in formal letters the verb write is sometimes used as a performative: I write to inform you that . . . (But in a more informal style I am writing . . . is preferred.)"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/55300/3281).

Answer (score 8):

"Look forward to" is a phrasal verb, in which "to" is a preposition; it is a part of the phrase, not the part of the infinitive hear.  So it takes a noun or the -ing form of a verb,  even you use the phrase in the progressive form. So your first sentence is OK grammatically, but the second one isn't. It should be:

I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *hearing* on both.

Also the second example is not a question, but basically a shortened form of the first example. Definitely informal.

> I look forward to **hearing** from you.
>
> (I am) looking forward to **hearing** from you.

*to* is part of *looking forward to* (some action). Not the infinitive form of the verb.

Answer (score 1):

The word “to” in this phrase is slightly confusing because it is usually used to introduce a verb, as in “want to” or “have to”. Even though saying “I want to hear from you” is completely correct, “to look forward to” employs a different pattern:

> I look forward to [a thing you would like to happen]

Obviously, “hear” is not a thing, so it wouldn’t make much sense to “look forward to hear from you”. The thing you are looking forward to is “hearing from you”:

> I look forward to hearing from you. (correct)
>   I look forward to hear from you. (wrong)

As for the question whether to use “I look forward to” or “I am looking forward to”, some people consider the two completely interchangeable, but most find the phrase with “look forward to” somewhat formal and best suited for formal correspondence, whereas “to be looking forward to” is more informal and friendly:

> I look forward to hearing from you. (correct in formal writing)
>   I am looking forward to hearing from you. (correct in an informal context)