# Is here a grammatical error?

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

> This guy needs ***to keeping writing*** such stuff.

I heard this in the first time. As far as I know, it should be used ***"to keep writing"*** in this sentence.

Is this because of the gerund-related rule?

Comment: You are right: "to keeping writing" is incorrect. "To keep writing" or "to keep on writing" would both be correct.

Comment: I wrote [an answer to a similar question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/71162/3281) once. If you don't know why in *He used to live in Frankfurt, but he's not used to living in cold weather*, the first one is *to live* but the second one is *to living*, I'd advise you to read it.